# saving a model I get: module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration' has no attribute 'get_registered_name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to save my ternsorflow model I get this error message. What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    # define the neural network architecture
    model.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_dim=hidden_dim, activation="relu")
    )
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes))

    k += 1
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=["mse", "accuracy"],
    )

    history = model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        verbose=0,
    )

    folder = "model_mlp_lm"
    file = f"m{k}_model"
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
    path = f"{folder}/{file}"
    if os.path.isfile(path) is False:
        model.save(path)
```

> module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration' has no attribute 'get_registered_name'

This is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\hijik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\_lodestar\personality-prediction\finetune_models\MLP_LM.py", line 273, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 1450, in _build_meta_graph_impl
    object_graph_proto = _serialize_object_graph(
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 1022, in _serialize_object_graph
    _write_object_proto(obj, obj_proto, asset_file_def_index,
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py", line 1061, in _write_object_proto
    registered_name = registration.get_registered_name(obj)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration' has no attribute 'get_registered_name'
```

Comment: the full stack trace would help rather than just the error. 99% of the module has no attribute xyz issues is a problem with mismatched versions, so check what version you are using and if it has this functionality. if not, go check on the code base which version has it and try to update.

Comment: Can you mention what tensorflow version you are using. Thanks.

Comment: tensorflow version is 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your tensorflow version is older or up-to-date.

This seems to be a newer module https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/get_registered_name

Make sure you have this version of tensorflow installed in your environment

```
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
```

I don't know about the dataset so I assumed a small one.
This is the code  I ran

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

# Define placeholder values
hidden_dim = 2
n_classes = 2
lr = 0.001
epochs = 10
batch_size = 32

# Create a simple dataset
x_train = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
y_train = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

# Convert y_train to one-hot encoded format
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=n_classes)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Define the neural network architecture
model.add(
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_dim=hidden_dim, activation="relu")
)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes))

k = 0  # Initialize k
k += 1  # Increment k
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["mse", "accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    verbose=0,
)

folder = "model_mlp_lm"
file = f"m{k}_model"
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
path = f"{folder}/{file}"
if os.path.isfile(path) is False:
    model.save(path)
```

And it ran fine

Comment: When I upgraded to tensorflow version 2.11 my code didn't work for other reasons which I tried to fix. In the end I had to upgrade it to version 2.8 and then it did work. I have only just fixed it, you deserve your bounty although that has expired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.saved_model.save` on the model object which will work with Keras. Or, you can use the keras saving and loading API, with `tf.keras.saving.save_model()` or its alias `model.save()` (*not what you're doing now* see below). Either formats can be called to save a model to disk. The former, `tf.saved_model.save`, is the newer means of saving TensorFlow SavedModel format (recommended), and the latter:

```
tf.keras.saving.save_model(model, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None, **kwargs)
```

supports both saving a model as a TensorFlow SavedModel or (backwards compatible) HDF5 file. In your code, you are calling the save method from the previous API locations `keras.models`, and not the new namespace, `keras.saving`, where all saving utilities have been moved. The other locations will exist indefinitely according to the release notes but it's recommended to use one of the newer options. Since you can call `tf.keras.Model.save` to save the entire model, which in your case looks like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(...)
model.compile(...)
model.save('model')
```

...but, `model.save()` also serves as an alias for `tf.keras.saving.save_model()`. I think it might be safer to use `tf.keras.saving.save_model(model, model_path)` instead of trying the alias (if you went the keras api route). Or, you can avoid any name confusion by trying tf.saved_model.save(model, model_path) first.

Also, when you call `model.save(path)`, '`save('path/to/model')`' creates a SavedModel directory at 'path/to/model'. So, your conditional: `if os.path.isfile(path) is False` will always be true because the path, had it been previously created, would not be a file, but a directory. If you did in fact want a file instead of tf SavedModel folder, you could use:

```
tf.keras.saving.save_model(model, model_path, overwrite=True, save_format='h5')
```

otherwise, I'd probably recommend trying this first:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_path)
```

Regarding the paths at the end: you use the parameter `exist_ok=True`. By default, `os.makedirs()` raises an OSError if the directory already exists but setting this to True suppresses the `FileExistsError` and overwrites the existing directory. After this, you check whether the file exists (even though it'd be a directory) but in either case it would always evaluate to true. If you checked for `os.path.isfile(path)`, that'd be true that it is not a file (and you didn't specify that option by passing a .h5/.keras file). If you checked for `os.path.isdir(path)`, this would also evaluate to true because you just wrote a new empty "model_mlp_lm" over the existing one so checking for a model dir within that dir doesn't make sense (it's empty).

create the output directory outside of whatever loop you're in

then, try this:

```
output_dir = "model_mlp_lm"
model_dir = f"m{k}_model"
assert os.path.exists(output_dir)
model_path = os.path.join(output_dir, model_dir)
if not os.path.isdir(model_path):
    tf.saved_model.save(model, model_path)
```

I hope this helps, these are my thoughts without a minimum reproducible snippet or the full stack trace

Comment: Hi Harriet, I appreciate your answer. I tried your suggested code but I got the same error. I have posted the stack trace in the original question, maybe that will help?